# Passing hash of parameters to link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have a number of link_to's with the same parameters. I want to DRY these out, is it possible to pass a hash of parameters to link to?

```
link_to 'User Profile', @user, remote: true, disable_with: 'loading', class: 'btn'
```

How can I pass parameters in for example a hash to the link_to method? I tried the following in vain

```
args = {remote: true, disable_with: 'loading', class: 'btn'}
link_to 'User Profile', @user, args
```

Comment: What's not working? Everything, or just the "disable_with"?

Comment: I get an error, everything is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by having a look at [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

The method is define as such:

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

So, yes. You can.

UPDATE:

As requested, here's an example:

```
link_args = {remote: true, data: {disable_with: 'loading'}, class: 'btn'}
link_to 'User Profile', @user, link_args
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example in the context of the example given in the question?

Comment: Done ... hopefully that makes more sense now.

Comment: ahhhh, i realized what I was doing wrong, if you pass in more arguments in the link_to with the hash, you will get an error, the only way to pass in more arguments is to merge them in ```link_args.merge!({:class => 'btn'}```. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

On [`link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) helper you have this semantic:

```
link_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

i am not recommended separate options if you want `DRY` write application helper
in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def my_link_to(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    link_to('User Profile', @user, arg1, arg2, arg3)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example in the context of the example given in the question?